# Find date of first occurrence at the group level in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to build a query that retrieves the date field for the first time a particular occurrence is recorded, at the ID level. Below's 'FIRST_DATE' field is what I'm trying to achieve.

In this example, October 2020 is the first date that ID_FIELD 1 has a non-zero value, so Oct 2020 is applied as the FIRST_DATE for all ID_FIELD 1 rows. The intention is to be able to calculate the amount of time passed since an ID's value has changed from 0 to 1. Using Oracle SQL Developer.

| ID_FIELD | DATE_FIELD | VALUE | FIRST_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-JUL-20 | 0 | 01-OCT-20 |
| 1 | 01-AUG-20 | 0 | 01-OCT-20 |
| 1 | 01-SEP-20 | 0 | 01-OCT-20 |
| 1 | 01-OCT-20 | 1 | 01-OCT-20 |
| 1 | 01-NOV-20 | 1 | 01-OCT-20 |
| 1 | 01-DEC-20 | 1 | 01-OCT-20 |
| 2 | 01-JUL-20 | 0 | 01-AUG-20 |
| 2 | 01-AUG-20 | 1 | 01-AUG-20 |
| 2 | 01-SEP-20 | 1 | 01-AUG-20 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytic version of `min`, combined with a case expression:

```
select id_field, date_field, value,
  min(case when value != 0 then date_field end) over (partition by id_field) as first_date
from your_table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=612baecc106b6579f65c3664d6daed4f), including a couple of versions that calculates the elapsed days, depending on eactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! Follow-up question: if the value resets from 1 in one month to 0 the next and then back to 1 again the following, how do I modify this to choose the first date where the MOST RECENT run of value = 1 began?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id_field, MIN(DECODE(VALUE, 0, NULL, DATE_FIELD))
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id_field
```

You can then use that as part of your update statement.